# Cannot log in to phpMyAdmin even after configuration

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I just set up WAMP server. My port 80 was already in use so I changed the following lines in the Apache's `httpd.conf` file to make use of the port number 8080.

[image: httpd.conf file]

Then I changed MySQL's root password to `abc123` using the MySQL console. Everything is fine up to this point.

Then I configured the phpMyAdmin's setup script (*config.inc* file) as follows (through the browser using the GUI). And I saved the configurations.

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.4.10.1 setup script
 * Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2012 12:42:11 +0000
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 8080;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'abc123';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '4fcdfe94a0e6c7.79135356';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

But still I can't log in to phpMyAdmin even when I give the correct user credentials. It doesn't give me any error messages. Just takes a really long time loading and goes to a blank page with a URL like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=d30e16bb6e28ae70e8c2ed12a9c4e61f
```

I don't know what else to do. Is there a step I'm missing out on? Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! The port number here `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 8080;` is not the port for the localhost. It is the MySQL's port number. Which should be left blank as the default setting. I didn' know that before. Everything's working fine now.

Comment: If you put it as blank, it will use port 3306.